# Скрипты Unity2d

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio

я не могу писать скрипты в Юнити.
При создании скрипта я захожу в редактирование скрипта и там открывает Visual Studio 2019. Пишу код.. Он не форматируется в свой цвет. И при запуске игры выдает ошибку.

[image: Код]

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 1):

У вас сразу же ошибка в RigidBody2d - опечатки в названии типа переменной.

Comment: Ошибка при запуске игры в плеймоде из-за ошибки в исходнике текста. исправите RigidBody2D - должно быть всё в порядке.

Comment: Оно мне даже подсказок не даёт, пишу Rigid.. и пусто и так повсюду.

Comment: Исправил код как вы сказали, так же ничего не работает.

Comment: Вы добавили компонент RigidBody2D (а не просто RigidBody, например) в инспекторе?

Comment: Ну я смотрел видео урок, переписал код а оно чёт ..

Comment: Так ведь чисто переписи исходника недостаточно.  Надо ещё добавить в объект соответствующий компонент. Найдите вкладку Inspector, нажмите Add Component, выберите пункт RigidBody2D (можете ввести в выпадающем поисковике). После этого всё  должно заработать.

Comment: Да я эго добавил к спрайту. Добавил ещё до написания этого вопроса. На самом спрайте добавил RogidBody2d верно?

Comment: *Rigidbody2D, да. Тогда программа должна запускаться.

Comment: Также, вы присвоили переменной Rigidbody тип Vector2. В Unity подобное, по-моему, не работает - вызывает ошибку. используется обходной путь:

Comment: Vector2 movement = New Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*12f, rb.velocity.y);
rb.velocity=movement;

Comment: Не то что бы я писал, я смотрел гайд. Завтра попробую и отпишу вам.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное :) А оно работает по типу написал часть и оно дописывает например напишу Rigid.. а оно Rigitbody2d, и как-то подсвечиваться?

Comment: void Update()
    {
        if(Inout.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jump();
        }
    }

    void jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 14f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          А теперь прыжок не могу сделать.

Comment: Сразу бросается в глаза опечатка if (Input.GetKey...), также для прыжков обычно используется не transform.up, а Vector2.up. Ещё напоминаю, что в данном случае будет неоднократный прыжок в воздухе (не как в обычном платформере, а как в FlappyBird, например)

Comment: Если будут ещё какие-нибудь вопросы, лучше напишите на мою почту JustTestingV@yandex.com - а то комментариев уже слишком много в этом вопросе. Не обещаю, что смогу на всё ответить - но могу хотя бы попробовать. :)

Answer (score 0):

А библиотеку UnityEngine добавили?

```
using UnityEngine;
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).